# Adding legend to R Pie chart causes "plot.new has not been called yet" error when run via R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, legend

This question has been asked before but not in the context of R markdown.

**The below code works when ran in a .R file but the same code fails when run via R markdown.**

Using the standard base plotting (no library import), in my .rmd I have

```
pie(sex.freq, main = "Pie Chart of Gender", labels = pie.labels, col = rainbow(length(gender.freq)))
```

this works fine and shows:
[image]

I then try and add a legend:

```
legend("topright", c("Male", "Female"), fill = rainbow(length(gender.freq)))
```

this gives the error:

```
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

It does not matter if I do a full knit of the file or ctrl+enter each line, both give the error

I do not want to use ggplot2 here.

Why is there an issue doing this via R Markdown?

Comment: Do you have the legend call in a different code chunk? If so, thats your problem. If not, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @AndS. Thanks! Yes! It was a different code chunk! Great, thanks! Please convert your comment to an answer